# Pass a params from a file called into a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to know how I can run a file.rb directly into controller.
For example, I have followed the tuto for Twilio, and it's working using the command : "ruby test.rb" into terminal to run the file test.rb into the app folder.

But I don't know how I can run this file directly into my controller. For example :

```
TestController.rb 
 def test_sms
  run "test.rb"
 end
end
```

**UPDATE**

According to @Seth answer, the good solution looks like that.

My file :

```
class Test
  attr_accessor :body

  def initialize
    # ...
  end

  def do_something
    self.body = "Test string params"
  end
end
```

And my controller :

```
require "path/to/file"
class TestController < ApplicationController
  def test_sms
    test = Test.new
    test.do_something
    body = test.body
    print body
  end
end
```

Comment: What does `test.rb` look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a test file such as the following:

```rb
# your file
class Test
  def initialize
    # ...
  end

  def do_something
    # ...
  end
end
```

All you need to do is require said file and then invoke whatever it is you need to:

```rb
# your controller
require "path/to/file"
class TestController < ApplicationController
  def test_sms
    test = Test.new
    test.do_something
  end
end
```

Comment: It's exactly what I'm looking for, but I have a problem to pass params generated on my file to the controller 

For example: 

The line " print result.body " is working, so I've try to create a params " @body = result.body " but I cannot acces it into my controller. Any Idea ?

Comment: @jacquesMesnet I'd have to see the code to understand more, but it sounds like you need to define `attr_reader :body` within the class so that the instance variable can be read within the scope of its caller.

Comment: I have remade a answer with the code that I'm trying to run bellow

Answer (score 0):

According to @Seth answer, the good solution looks like that. But I cannot access to the params @body created on the file.rb through the controller. Any idea ?

My file :

```
class Test
  def initialize
    # ...
  end

  def do_something
    @body = "Test string params"
  end
end
```

And my controller :

```
require "path/to/file"
class TestController < ApplicationController
  def test_sms
    test = Test.new
    test.do_something
    print @body
  end
end
```

Comment: Instead adding additional information through an answer or comment you should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59072982/edit) your original question.

Comment: `@body` in `TestController` is not the same as `@body` in `Test`. You should add an attribute reader to `Test` to read from the attribute. `attr_reader :body` just under `class Test`. Then in the controller use `print test.body`.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer, I've edit my post as you suggest to be cleaner. I test your solution right now, but I'm not really sure to understand it. I'm gonna look what is attr_reader on gg

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046831/why-use-rubys-attr-accessor-attr-reader-and-attr-writer

Comment: This was more usefull to explain my particular case : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133172/rails-attr-accessor-undefined-method-in-the-setter

Comment: Thanks @3limin4t0r !!